# How to replace string by another string when they include appostrophes?

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, escaping

```
sed -i 's/cfg._sections['styles']/t(cfg._sections['styles'])/g' *
```

I tried ", but it didn't help.

Comment: Double quotes do correctly fix the apostrophes, but you didn't realize because you have an additional problem with square brackets that must be fixed simultaneously to see any effect. Protip: it's much easier to fix a single problem at a time, so always try it on the smallest possible example you can think of like `echo "a 'b' c" | sed "s/'/X/g"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to escape special characters `[` and `]` in a regex:

```
sed -i "s/cfg._sections\['styles'\]/t(cfg._sections\['styles'\])/g" *
```

If your input contains a `.` then escape first `.`, too.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/cfg\._sections\['\''styles'\''\]/t(&)/g' file
```

Surround the sed commands by single quotes.

The `.`, `[` and `]` on the LHS of regexp represent any character, and the opening and closing of character classes see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions), and so must be escaped/quoted by prepending `\`.

The idiom `'\''` can be used to insert a `'`, this closes the opening `'` and at shell level introduces a `'` (again escaped/quoted) followed by another opening `'`.

The [&](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) in the RHS of a regexp represents what was captured by the LHS of the regexp.

N.B. The terms LHS and RHS stand for left-hand-side and right-hand-side respectively (`s/LHS/RHS/`).